# C preprocessor macro expansion - use calculations

Tags: c

I have something like, where I try to use macro expansion with a calculation resulting into a string of chars using C:

```
#define S_O(N, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, RI, GI, BI, RO, GO, BO) \
    "S" #N*2-1 "H;" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "Z;" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "M2;" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "PA" #X1 "," #Y1 ";" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "PB" #X2 "," #Y2 ";" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "W2,2;" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "R" #RO ";" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "G" #GO ";" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "B" #BO ";" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "A0;" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "BD0;" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "S;" \
    "S" #N*2-1 "S;" \
    "S" #N*2 "H;" \
    "S" #N*2 "Z;" \
    "S" #N*2 "M2;" \
    "S" #N*2 "PA" #X1 "," #Y1 ";" \
    "S" #N*2 "PB" #X2 "," #Y2 ";" \
    "S" #N*2 "W2,2;" \
    "S" #N*2 "R" #RI ";" \
    "S" #N*2 "G" #GI ";" \
    "S" #N*2 "B" #BI ";" \
    "S" #N*2 "A0;" \
    "S" #N*2 "BD0;" \
    "S" #N*2 "S;" \
    "S" #N*2 "S;"

/* later in the code is used like this: */
char buffer[1024]={0};
snprintf(1024, S_O(1, 10, 20, 1880, 1060, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255));
/* the output should be:
 * "S1H;S1Z;" etc.
 */
```

Obviously, this doesn't compile... How may I achieve my goal to avoid a function encapsulating this?

Comment: You have two problems, and only one of them can be solved in the macro. That's the strinngification of the macro arguments to concatenate them to the other strings. The second problem is the calculations, and that simply can't be solved within a macro.

Comment: What should be the output? `snprintf` needs a buffer. Should it be `"S" "1" "H;" "S" "1" "Z;" "...."`?

Comment: is there any upper limit on `N` ?

Comment: I edited my question and added a buffer variable and showed what the output should look like...

Comment: N is intended as uint8_t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I try to use macro expansion with a calculation resulting into a string

It is not possible to use just macro expansion to convert a result of calculation to a string. It is not (*feasibly) possible to use C preprocessor to convert the result of a calculation to a string.

> How may I achieve my goal to avoid a function encapsulating this?

Strongly prefer in such cases to use a better and more powerful pre-processor than C preprocessor, like M4, Jinja2, PHP, or generate the source code.

---

*feasibly: To convert the result of a calculation to a string in C preprocessor, you would have to enumerate **all possible cases** one by one and prepare a string for it.

```
// calculate.h

#if N*2 == 2
#define RESULT_OF_N_MUL_2 "2"
#elif N*2 == 4
#define RESULT_OF_N_MUL_2 "4"
// etc. for __any__ number you want to handle
#endif

#if N*2-1 == 1
#define RESULT_OF_N_MUL_2_MINUS_1 "1"
#elif N*2-1 == 3
#define RESULT_OF_N_MUL_2_MINUS_1 "3"
// etc. for __any__ number you want to handle
#endif

#define S_O() \
   "S" RESULT_OF_N_MUL_2_MINUS_1 "H;" \
   "S" RESULT_OF_N_MUL_2 "H;"

#undef N

// main.c
#define N 10
#include "calculate.h"
int main() {
   puts(S_O());
}
```

If you are open to such code, then you could use [boost/preprocessor](https://github.com/boostorg/preprocessor/blob/develop/include/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp#L33) and apply stringify operation after the expansion, which works suprisingly good:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
    
#define S_O(N) \
    "S" BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_SUB(BOOST_PP_MUL(N, 2), 1)) "H;"

int main() {
    puts(S_O(5)); // outputs "S9H;"
}
```

Behind the scenes, let's say `BOOST_PP_*` enumerate all possible cases of addition one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your edit: first part - cool implementation for a small range of N! On the other hand I have to use C only, because I'm using a microcontroller with very limited resources... Thx a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It's doable.

You can initialize a string as a normal array. It allows to do the computation over individual characters.

```
char x[] = "hello";
char y[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };
```

Each digit can be computed as `'0' + (value / (10**position)) % 10`.

Exemplary code that computes strings at compilation time for `2*x-1` and `y*y` where `x == 7` and `y == 11`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define D(X) ('0' + (X) % 10)
#define S3(X) D((X)/100), D((X)/10), D(X)
#define S_O(X, Y) { 'S', S3(2*X-1), 'H', ';', 'S', S3(Y*Y), 'A', ';', 0 }

int main() {
    char buf[] = S_O(7, 11);
    puts(buf);
}
```

It prints:

```
S013H;S121A;
```

Still not perfect, because it adds those extra heading zeros but it may be good enough for OP's application.

Comment: Great method, the only limitation of it, is that you have to specify the length of the resulting string from the number, you used 3 digits. But it would greatly reduce the cases in the code that uses X-macros that I've written in my answer, to `#if N<10 ... #elif N < 100` etc.

Comment: Indeed a very great implementation for this specific problem!